# Show that $\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^n$ for all $n ∈ N$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci numbers $F_n$ are recursively defined by

$F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1$

$F_{n+2} = F_{n+1} + F_n, n = 0,1,...$

i) Show that $\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^n$ for all $n ∈ N$.

ii) Show that $F_0^2 + F_1^2 + ...+F_n^2 = F_n F_{n+1}$ for all $n ∈ N$.

iii) Show that $F_{n-1} F_{n+1} - F_n^2 = (-1)^n$ for all $n ∈ N$.

Comment: The title and question i) are not the same. Also what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting recursive equations into matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858268/converting-recursive-equations-into-matrices)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, only a duplicate for (i).

Comment: Well, A) it answers part (iii) as well, B) there should be only one question.per post. It is highly likely that the other parts have been covered earlier as well.

Comment: I guess the easiest way it to multiply the equation by $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ and then the RHS is $$\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+2}&F_{n+1}\\F_{n+1}&F_{n}\end{bmatrix}$$ by assumption and you just need to evaluate $$\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+1}+F_n&F_{n+1}\\F_n+F_{n-1}&F_{n}\end{bmatrix}$$ which by the Fibonacci recursion however matches $$\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+2}&F_{n+1}\\F_{n+1}&F_{n}\end{bmatrix} \, .$$

For iii) just take the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to prove those by induction on $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

For example, the "induction step" for the second exercise is:

Suppose that $F_0^2+\cdots+F_n^2=F_nF_{n+1}$, then $$F_0^2+\cdots+F_n^2+F_{n+1}^2=F_nF_{n+1}+F_{n+1}^2=F_{n+1}(F_n+F_{n+1})=F_{n+1}F_{n+2}$$

Try the same approach in the other exercises. Don't forget the base cases.

Comment: It seems that (ii) and (iii) are meant to be solved using (i).

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

(i) Easy induction.

(ii)
Note that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}^2 = 
\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+1}^2+F_n^2&*\\*&*\end{bmatrix} 
$$

(iii) Take determinants.

Answer (score 0):

i) [Diagonalize](http://diagonalize%20%7B%7B1,1%7D,%7B1,0%7D%7D) the RHS matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 1&0\end{pmatrix}^n=
\begin{pmatrix}\psi&\phi\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\psi^n &0\\ 0&\phi^n\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}&\frac{\phi}{\sqrt{5}}\\ \frac1{\sqrt{5}}&-\frac{\psi}{\sqrt{5}}\end{pmatrix}=\\
\begin{pmatrix}\psi^{n+1}&\phi^{n+1}\\ \psi^n&\phi^n\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}&\frac{\phi}{\sqrt{5}}\\ \frac1{\sqrt{5}}&-\frac{\psi}{\sqrt{5}}\end{pmatrix}=\\
\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\phi^{n+1}-\psi^{n+1}}{\sqrt{5}}&\frac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}\\ \frac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}&\frac{\phi^{n-1}-\psi^{n-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\end{pmatrix}=\\
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\ F_n&F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$
Note: $\phi\cdot \psi=-1$.